# Why do methane molecules have 15 degrees of freedom?

Tags: thermodynamics, molecules

I've just been learning a little thermal chemistry including the equipartition theorem. As part of this, my textbook discusses how to figure out the degrees of freedom for different chemicals.

The answer to one of the exercises says methane has 15 degrees of freedom: 3 for translation, 3 for rotations and 9 for vibrations. I am confused by two of these.

Firstly the text says that diatomic molecules like oxygen gas only have 2 rotational degrees of freedom, because they can't rotate about their axis of symmetry. However methane has an axis of symmetry, so why does it have 3 rotational degrees?

Secondly I don't understand where all the vibration degrees of freedom come from. The molecule has 4 bonds, so wouldn't each bond have one degree for kinetic energy and one for potential energy, for a total of 8 degrees, not 9?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, but did you learn about wagging and twisting? Because those can account for the "missing" degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

15 is there because you have 5 atoms which can move independently, and we live in a 3D space, and $3\ \times\ 5\ =\ 15$.

3 of these are translational degrees of freedom, which you seem to agree with, so I'll just leave it at that.

3 are for rotations, because the methane molecule is **not linear**. Axes of symmetry are irrelevant: indeed, you may rotate methane around the axis of symmetry as well as around any other axis. Being or not being diatomic is hardly relevant either, except for the fact that all diatomic molecules are necessarily linear; however, the converse is not true.

Subtracting 3 and 3 from 15, we get 9, and that's how many vibrational degrees of freedom we have, because they can't be anything else. To *visualize* them is another story, and a great deal more difficult. Counting bonds doesn't help much. The separation of degrees into kinetic and potential is not a thing at all. You don't have to do that anyway. Write $15\ -\ 3\ -\ 3\ =\ 9$ and call it a day.

Comment: So, there's 9 vibrational degrees not because we counted them, but because there has to be 15 total and we only have one category left? Sure, it works, but that doesn't sound right...

Comment: Yes, that's right, even if doesn't feel so.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The book I've been working through is Schroeder. It says: "A diatomic molecule can also vibrate, as if the two atoms were held together by a spring. This vibration counts as two degrees of freedom, one for the vibrational kinetic energy and one for the potential energy". Wouldn't be the first time, but is this an error in the book?

Comment: My understanding is that the remaining 9 don't refer to any one atom, but interactions involving *pairs* (or even larger groups?) of atoms. [This page](https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Spectroscopy/Vibrational_Spectroscopy/Vibrational_Modes/Number_of_vibrational_modes_for_a_molecule) had some helpful visualizations.  Within the constraints of the molecule, the motion of any individual molecule has some affect on the others.

Comment: @chepner You are right. It is not even pairs, but mostly larger groups.

Comment: @leob That's plain nonsense. There is no such thing as a degree of freedom for kinetic or potential energy; instead, _every single_ vibrational degree of freedom represents a motion in which potential energy changes to kinetic and back. Moreover, a diatomic molecule has but **one** vibration.

Comment: The axis of rotation for diatomics only matters because the symmetry is $C_{\infty}$, i.e., rotation by any amount gives the exact same thing. Methane's axes are $C_2$ and $C_3$.

Comment: @Ivan Ok, that statement from the text had me thoroughly confused. So essentially by definition the rotational degrees of freedom are those that remain left after translational and rotational degrees? They don't correspond with different physical motions or vibration modes that can be counted?

Comment: They **do** correspond to certain physical motions, but it is somewhat challenging to tell which are those in particular. We weren't asked to do that. We had a simpler task: to count the vibrations, and that's how we did it.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I believe the idea of two degrees of freedom for a vibration is a poor attempt by Schroeder to explain that the average energy of an oscillator is $k_bT$ using equipartition because the mean value of any quadratically varying term in the energy is $\frac{1}{2}k_bT$.

Comment: I have to agree about this being nonsense. Either the total number of degrees of freedom or the vibrational number of degrees of freedom have to come from somewhere.

Comment: If someone wants to read more about this, the following article essentially explains the same thing in this answer with a bit more context beforehand and visuals for triatomic linear molecules: https://www.tec-science.com/thermodynamics/kinetic-theory-of-gases/equipartition-theorem/#Vibration

Comment: @chepner Yes , I believe the diagrams are true. 6 degrees of Freedom for pairs of atom and 3 degrees of freedom(along X,Y,Z) for entire molecule  would sum to 9.