# How does degree of freedom work

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory-of-gases

I understand that the degree of freedom is the number of ways in which a molecule can  acquire energy. I don't want you to explain the definition, but I want to see how it works. Please explain how is that a real thing, I want to see it. Try to describe the ways in which the molecule can acquire energy . I really can't see it.

Comment: Forget the energy. Degrees of freedom are the ways in which the molecule can stretch or bend.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Whoa what is that sir. How can we tell the ways in which molecules bend. Why can't they bend however they want to. This is more confusing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the degrees of freedom?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/91881/what-are-the-degrees-of-freedom)

Comment: Why can't you bend your arm however you want to?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I don't study biology. But it maybe due to the bone joint design. Sir maybe I get this: Nature has its own designs

Comment: OK, forget the arm. Think of a diatomic molecule. In what way(s) can it stretch or bend?

Comment: Both atoms can go upwards and go sideways and they can do it opposite directions . They can go at angles. They can bend around anywhere in the 360 degrees they got

Comment: Sure, but how many variables do you need to describe the way they are positioned relative to each other?

Comment: @IvanNeretin 3 maybe?

Comment: Well, what are those 3?

Comment: @IvanNeretin distance and angle between them ?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I first thought you asked about coordinates sir. Then I saw variables and the word "relative"

Comment: What's an angle between the _two_ points?

Comment: @IvanNeretin that not defined. But we can draw a horizontal passing through one point and specify the other's orientation with the angle . Right sir?

Comment: No. Imagine a molecule in which the two atoms are 2Å apart and one is above the other. Now imagine a similar molecule in which the two atoms are 2Å apart and both are in the same horizontal plane. Just how are they different? They aren't.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Ok sir then I got it wrong  . I'm listening

Comment: See, there is only one variable: it is the distance between them.

Comment: @IvanNeretin ok sir